# Convert chr to dttm

Tags: r

I have a df with two columns (started_at,ended_at). I converted them from chr to dttm

```
df <- df %>% mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), ~ as.POSIXct(.x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") %>% ymd_hms()))
```

but later i found that in each column that dates is registered in two formats, for example; one of them is in Year-Month-Day H:M:S format and the other one is in Day-month-Year H:M:S format.

```
# dummy dataframe example
id <- c(1:4) 
started_at <- c("2020-01-30 11:11:11", "2020-01-29 11:11:11" , "2020-01-28 11:11:11" , "13-01-20 11:11:11" )
ended_at <- c("2020-01-31 11:11:11", "2020-02-02 11:11:11" , "2020-01-29 11:11:11" , "14-01-20 11:11:11") 
bike_type <- c("E","C","E","E")

df <- data.frame(id,started_at,ended_at,bike_type, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I want a method to change both columns into a ymd_hms format. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added an answer, but I am assuming that the last row was supposed to be a 2020 date instead of 2013 and 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `lubridate` has a function `parse_date_time` that can parse many formmats in one call. But in the code below the formats must be in the right order, if the formats' order is swapped the results are wrong.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
})

id <- c(1:4) 
started_at <- c("2020-01-30 11:11:11", "2020-01-29 11:11:11" , "2020-01-28 11:11:11" , "13-01-20 11:11:11" )
ended_at <- c("2020-01-31 11:11:11", "2020-02-02 11:11:11" , "2020-01-29 11:11:11" , "14-01-20 11:11:11") 
bike_type <- c("E","C","E","E")

df <- data.frame(id,started_at,ended_at,bike_type, stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>% mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), ~ parse_date_time(.x, orders = c("dmy HMS", "ymd HMS"))))
#>   id          started_at            ended_at bike_type
#> 1  1 2020-01-30 11:11:11 2020-01-31 11:11:11         E
#> 2  2 2020-01-29 11:11:11 2020-02-02 11:11:11         C
#> 3  3 2020-01-28 11:11:11 2020-01-29 11:11:11         E
#> 4  4 2020-01-13 11:11:11 2020-01-14 11:11:11         E
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Or simpler, using the dots argument to `across`.

```
df %>% mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), parse_date_time, orders = c("dmy HMS", "ymd HMS")))
```

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know about that one! So, I was just playing around with this, and it looks like it can handle date formats going back and forth between the 2 formats. But it just has to have a `dmy HMS`, first. Is that correct?

Comment: @AndrewGB Yes, if not it will coerce the dates in the last row, they are also valid as ymd.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have dates in different orders in the same columns, we can create new columns with both orders (i.e., `dmy` and `ymd`). The `dmy` will just return `NA` for those that are not in that order (i.e., that are in `ymd`). Next, we convert to `ymd`, then we can combine (via `coalesce`) these 2 columns together each for the start and end dates. Then, just select the original column names.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), ~ dmy_hms(.x), .names = "{.col}_dmy"),
         across(c(started_at, ended_at), ~ ymd_hms(.x), .names = "{.col}_ymd"),
         started_at = coalesce(started_at_dmy, started_at_ymd),
         ended_at = coalesce(ended_at_dmy, ended_at_ymd)) %>% 
  select(names(df))
```

**Output**

```
  id          started_at            ended_at bike_type
1  1 2020-01-30 11:11:11 2020-01-31 11:11:11         E
2  2 2020-01-29 11:11:11 2020-02-02 11:11:11         C
3  3 2020-01-28 11:11:11 2020-01-29 11:11:11         E
4  4 2020-01-13 11:11:11 2020-01-14 11:11:11         E
```

However, if the last row is supposed to be 2013 and 2014 instead of 2020, then you can just use `lubridate`.

```
df %>%
    mutate(across(c(started_at, ended_at), ~ ymd_hms(.x)))
```

*Output*

```
  id          started_at            ended_at bike_type
1  1 2020-01-30 11:11:11 2020-01-31 11:11:11         E
2  2 2020-01-29 11:11:11 2020-02-02 11:11:11         C
3  3 2020-01-28 11:11:11 2020-01-29 11:11:11         E
4  4 2013-01-20 11:11:11 2014-01-20 11:11:11         E
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = 1:4, started_at = c("2020-01-30 11:11:11", 
"2020-01-29 11:11:11", "2020-01-28 11:11:11", "13-01-20 11:11:11"
), ended_at = c("2020-01-31 11:11:11", "2020-02-02 11:11:11", 
"2020-01-29 11:11:11", "14-01-20 11:11:11"), bike_type = c("E", 
"C", "E", "E")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```